# Using a Model Method instead of db column for ChartKick / Groupdate gem

Tags: arrays, json, ruby-on-rails, group-by, chartkick

I'm using ChartKick to display a line chart and using a charts controller to avoid timeout. I am also using the groupdate gem

Is it possible to use a model method as the tally for the chart / group_by_day function - i can only seem to get it to work if i use DB columns

This works - total_spend being a column in the user database

```
render json: users.group_by_week(:created_at).average(:total_spend)
```

This does not - total_spend_in_time

```
render json: users.group_by_week(:created_at).average(:total_spend_in_time)
```

neither does

```
render json: users.group_by_week(:created_at).average(&:total_spend_in_time)
```

Here is the User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
def total_spend_in_time
    total = 0
    if Subscription::Payment.where(user_id:self.id).any? 
        sub_payments = Subscription::Payment.where(user_id:self.id)
        sub_payments.each do |sub|
          total += sub.payment_amount
        end
    end

    if Order.where(buyer_id:self.id).where(status:"success").any? 
        order_payments = Order.where(buyer_id:self.id).where(status:"success")
        order_payments.each do |ord|
          total += ord.total_price
        end

    end

    total
  end
end
```

Comment: https://dev.to/adamlombard/ruby-class-methods-vs-instance-methods-4aje

Comment: Also, If I'm not wrong `average` is an Activerecord method and returns the avg. of a column. you might wanna use scopes instead.

Comment: i don't think its possible with the groupdate gem, afaik you must use count, sum, minimum, maximum, or average - does this mean I'm restricted to only DB entries?